# Wamp MySQL will not start: unknown option '--skip-locking'

Tags: mysql, wamp

I just installed wamp and port 80 is not being used, i fixed all of the ini's and conf's and what not, wampmyswld will not start, i tried from services manually, and it also fails everytime i try to start wamp. im guessing youll need more info, so ill add it per your request

added:
skype is completely uninstalled

heres the mysql log:

```
2013-08-01 05:07:13 6132 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-08-01 05:07:13 6132 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-08-01 05:07:13 6132 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-08-01 05:07:13 6132 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-08-01 05:07:13 6132 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-08-01 05:07:13 6132 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2013-08-01 05:07:13 6132 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-08-01 05:07:13 6132 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-08-01 05:07:13 6132 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-08-01 05:07:13 6132 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-08-01 05:07:13 6132 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.12 started; log sequence number 1625977
2013-08-01 05:07:13 6132 [ERROR] wampmysqld: unknown option '--skip-locking'
2013-08-01 05:07:13 6132 [ERROR] Aborting

2013-08-01 05:07:13 6132 [Note] Binlog end
2013-08-01 05:07:13 6132 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2013-08-01 05:07:13 6132 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2013-08-01 05:07:13 6132 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2013-08-01 05:07:13 6132 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2013-08-01 05:07:13 6132 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2013-08-01 05:07:13 6132 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
```

Comment: SKYPE is blocking it "silently". I had such issue

Comment: Run as Administrator (right click icon wamp). Or check log file mysql service

Comment: click wamp->Apache->Service->Test Port 80 and see which program is using port 80

Comment: @legendinmaking i already said that no program is using port 80

Comment: Since your question does not seem to be about neither Apache nor PHP, I've changed the title and retagged. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 11):

`--skip-locking` was removed in MySQL 5.5.

Just edit your my.ini and replace `skip-locking` with `skip-external-locking`

Comment: This solved it for me - I've been running the local server fine for a few months, but suddenly it stopped working and got stuck in an upgrade loop. The key to realising this was by looking in the log, e.g. sudo tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log, if it keeps trying and failing to upgrade with the line [ERROR] [MY-000068] [Server] unknown option '--skip-locking', then this fix will work. Thank very much - I only spent an hour on this, could have been much worse!

Answer (score 2):

Your log belongs to MySQL. MySQL is not a web server and does not use port 80. The error is pretty self-explanatory:

> 2013-08-01 05:07:13 6132 [ERROR] wampmysqld: unknown option '--skip-locking'

Do you mean --[skip-external-locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_external-locking) by chance?

Comment: im not sure what your asking

Comment: i searched my.ini for skip-locking, but only skip-networking and skip-federated are present

Comment: i found skip-locking in my.cnf, located on the root of my hardrive, and i changed it to skip-external-locking, and made sure it is NOT commented out, but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have an my.ini in C:\Windows folder from the other version of mysql ? Change the option there and it will be OK. If can not do it, try to rename these files, or move to the other location. I have that issue and it worked.